# Why the private variable is not generating error?

Tags: python

```
class Dice:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value=22
    def showvalue(self):
        return self.__value

d=Dice()
d.__value=6
print(d.showvalue())
```

I am learning OOPs with Python. In the above program
why no error is coming for setting `__value` outside the class `Dice`, but the value is not getting set. I am getting `22` as return from `showvalue()`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `python` uses name mangling, changing the property names of double underscore elements, for example:

```py
class Dice:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value=22
    def showvalue(self):
        return self.__value

d=Dice()
print(dir(d))
>>> ['_Dice__value', '__class__', ... , 'showvalue']
```

You will not find `__value`, instead it's accesible in the class instance as 
 `_Dice__value`:

```py
d=Dice()
print(d._Dice__value)

>>> 22
```

You can modify it:

```py
d=Dice()
d._Dice__value = 6
print(d._Dice__value)
>>> 6
print(d.showvalue())
>>> 6
```

So basically you shouldn't use `__` or `_` outside of the class declaration unless you know exactly what you are doing, and even so that practice is not recommended.

Edit: as stated by @martineau it might be useful to explain what `d.__value` is doing:

```py
d=Dice()
d.__value=6

print(dir(d))
>>> ['_Dice__value', '__class__', ... , '__value', 'showvalue'] 

print(d.__value)
>>> 6

print(d.showvalue())
>>> 22
```

In this case, you are adding a new property to the class instance `d`: `__value`. `python` only enforces `pseudo-private` attribute rules when defining the class. Remember that at this point the `d` instance has two different properties: `__value` and `_Dice__value`. Anything inside the class `Dice` when it was defined that uses `self.__value` maps to `_Dice__value` and since `__value` was dynamically added later to `d` it can be accessed outside the class declaration.

Comment: Should probably also explain what the `d.__value=6` is doing…

Comment: but why d.__value=6 not generating error when we are trying to access private variable outside class. please udpate.

Comment: Hmm... how do `self.__value` "inside the class" and `d.__value` "outside the class" differ? Since `self` is not a special keyword but just another variable, how does it make a difference?

Comment: @HeapOverflow pardon my poor choice of words. There is a difference between class declaration and class instance usage. `self.__value` is mangled after instantiation while `d.__value` is not, they refer to two different variables. It's true that `self` is not a reserved keyword, I used it to make clearer the difference.

Comment: Oh I didn't mind your word choice :-). It was just not clear to me how it differs. Like, do `self` and `d` refer to different objects somehow, or is the "execution context" of "being inside" or "being outside" relevant somehow, or is the code changed somehow? I now did `import dis; dis.dis(Dice().showvalue)` and that solved it for me, showing that it's *compiled* to different *bytecode*. I suggest to add that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

necessary to create a function to edit the private variable

```
def change(self, s):
    self.__value = s
```

the code will look like this:

```
class Dice:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value= 22

    def showvalue(self):
        return self.__value

    def change(self, s):
        self.__value = s


d = Dice()
d.change(10)
print(d.showvalue())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following at the end of your code...

```
print(d.__dict__)
```

`__dict__` is the underlying attributes and values associated with that class. Using that you should see 2 values set in your class

```
{'_Dice__value': 22, '__value': 6}
```

The one internal to the class has been prefixed with "`_classname`". You can either use that to edit the value or create a setter function on the class like this...

```
def setvalue(self, value):
    self.__value = value
```

Comment: please update why two __value variables in dict . what is the difference between the two.